# people requesting to connect and mine on facebook are legit?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-reward

I recently joined a facebook group and lot of folks have been bombarding me to join my bitcoin wallet with some server for mining. Precisly, one of the guys mentioned as it is below

> KEEP your Btc in your wallet (normal 0.03) and start
>   earning If you have blockchain wallet you can start to earn FREE by
>   connecting your wallet direct to servers!!!  No investment, no ads, no
>   refferals! PM for info

are these worth it? can they be trusted for mining association and all?

Comment: No and no, just ignore them. They will most probably steal your money.

Comment: wallet id i am sharing with them is anyway empty, all my btc are in different wallet...can it still be stolen by them?

Answer (score 3):

I would stay away from all of these. Nigerian princes are on facebook too. Their tactic is probably to:

1. Find a person who is interested in bitcoin, but has little technical know-how about the system.
2. Convince them that they can make easy money. Throw in some buzzwords, make it seem like they are doing something nobody else is doing.
3. Gain access to their private keys by convincing the user to share them. If this does not work, convince the user that they need to install a bit of software to get the mining to work / to work faster. This software is most probably a keylogger and a mining tool that mines crypto without the user's knowledge.
4. Profit and Repeat.

Never trust something told to you by a single user on the internet. Even this post. Always verify the information at different parts of the internet. In this case: the stackexchange page, the bitcoin subreddit, the bitcointalk forum. These are hubs for people with the same interest and deep technical knowledge.